# Sum data frame rows according to column date

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame resembling this structure:

```
Name     2021-01-01     2021-01-02     2021-01-03   
Banana       5              23            23
Apple        90             2             15 
Pear         39             7             18
```

The actual dataframe has dates spanning a much larger period of time.

How do I aggregate the columns together so that each column represents a week, with the data from each day being summed to form the weekly value? Giving something like this:

```
Name     2021-01-01     2021-01-08     2021-01-15   
Banana       50             23            62
Apple        34             34            81 
Pear         13             18            29
```

I've looked at the aggregate function but it doesn't seem quite right for this purpose.

Comment: Are the dates consecutive (one day apart) in the real data?

Comment: yeah they are consecutive

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice solution from which I learnt a lot. R really is powerful. After the edit, the output now has as column names the dates of the start of the respective weeks, see below.

**Data**

```
example <- data.frame(Name = "Banana", 
                    "2021-01-01" = 1, 
                    "2021-01-02" = 3,  
                    "2021-01-10" = 2, 
                    "2021-02-02" = 3)
> example
    Name X2021.01.01 X2021.01.02 X2021.01.10 X2021.02.02
1 Banana           1           3           2           3
```

**Code**

```
out <- example %>% 
           tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(-Name)) %>% 
                  mutate(Name2 = as.Date(name, format = "X%Y.%m.%d")) %>% 
                         mutate(week = lubridate::week(Name2)) %>%
                                   group_by(week) %>% 
                                         mutate(Sum = sum(value)) %>% 
                                             mutate(Dates = lubridate::ymd("2021-01-01") + lubridate::weeks(week - 1)) %>% 
                                ungroup %>% 
                                       select(-name, -value, -Name2, -week) %>%
                                                     group_by_all %>% 
                                                            unique %>%
                                                      tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = Name, values_from = Sum, names_from = Dates)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   Name [1]
  Name   `2021-01-01` `2021-01-08` `2021-01-29`
  <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Banana            4            2            3
```

Comment: This is very cool, although you loose the first column and the dates aren't in the column names which is what I need

Comment: I edited my answer, see above. Now they are in the column names! Actually, the dates of the start of the respective week are in the columns.

Comment: Note that `week` here is relative to January 1st: so week 1 = January 1-7, week 2 = January 8-14 and so on. From your question this is probably what you wanted, but a week could be defined in other ways.